# Are semicolons allowed in device attributes?

Tags: fiware-orion

I was trying to update an entity with a semicolon inside an attribute:

```
{
    "name": "Accelerometer",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "0;0;0",
    "metadatas": [
        {
            "name": "TimeInstant",
            "type": "ISO8601",
            "value": "2019-12-17T14:13:01.398Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

and got

```
{
    "errorCode": {
        "code": "400",
        "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
        "details": "Illegal value for JSON field"
    }
}
```

Removing the ; solve the error. However, is this behaviour the one expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's normal behavior. Please have a look to the [forbidden characters Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did not think about that section because the response message stated that it was illegal for JSON, not for the attribute